# Empty /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Tags: xorg.conf

I'm trying to enable hibernation on my laptop, and discovered that my problems could have something to do with my Nvidia drivers. So I found [this fine document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia?action=show&redirect=NvidiaLaptopBinaryDriverSuspend#Suspend.2FHibernation) on help.ubuntu.com which tells me to change some settings in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. But it's empty! So what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming creating a new xorg.conf file would help, try the following:

```
Xorg -configure
```

After your xorg.conf file is created successfully, you can follow the steps your document is referring to.

P.S. More information about your operating system and what you've tried so far may be helpful to share here if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With NVIDIA, you could use the `nvidia-settings` dialog to generate a xorg config.
In the "X ServerDisplay Configuration Tab" it can be saved using the "Save to X Configuration file" button.

In Ubuntu, the file should go to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-nividia.conf`. You may edit the appropriate section with additional items.

I've tried hibernation on many laptops/thinkpads that had NVIDIA cards to no avail. On my workstation I've got a GTX 760 that perfectly hibernates, but it is my first and only NVIDIA card that could do it.